# XGBoost on GPU is killing the kernel (On Ubuntu)

Tags: python, gpu, xgboost

The kernel dies every time I run XGBoost on GPU with this code:

> params = {'tree_method': 'gpu_exact', 'max_depth': 100, 'learning_rate': 0.1}
>   dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X_train,y_train )
>   xgb.train(params, dtrain, evals=[(dtrain, "train")])

I get:

```
Kernel died - restarting
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the main problem is max_depth=100, xgboost builds trees layer by layer so a full tree of depth 100 will be too large. Try using values up to 12 for example.

Comment: By the way, if you are using GPU gradient boosting, I suggest you to try catboost, which is currently the fastest GPU GBDT library. Here is the nvidia blogpost about it: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/catboost-fast-gradient-boosting-decision-trees/